# SQL Bulk Copy not working with sparse column

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlbulkcopy

I am using **C#**'s **SQLBulkCopy** class to insert multiple rows into **SQL Server 2008 R2**.. It is working for normal table.. but not working for the table which has **sparse** column.

Do I need to set any extra settings for **sparse** column in **SQLBulkCopy**?

My code:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, null))
    {         
       foreach (DataColumn item in objectData.Columns)
              {
                  sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(item.ColumnName, item.ColumnName);
              }

          sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[" + tableName + "]";
          sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(objectData);
     }
```

I am getting this error:

**The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination**

Comment: Can you please show your work as well?

Comment: @SonerGönül I have added my code

Comment: And 'not working' means?? Error code? Exception?

Comment: I am getting this error:

**The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination**

Comment: Please post the list of columns in the actual instance of `objectData.Columns` and the table column schema (SQL)

Answer (score 0):

In bulk copy, the column names will be case sensitive. So if you are sure that both the source and destination has columns, then check whether the names of the columns matches. In case if the assigned column name at source is "Account" and destination column name is "ACCOUNT" it will not work out.

Answer (score 0):

It is not because of sparse columns. I have just created test app and it inserts data into table with sparse columns with no problem. Looks like one of datacolumn name has no corresponding column in sql table.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TestSparse
>     (
>       ID INT PRIMARY KEY ,
>       Descript VARCHAR(20) SPARSE NULL ,
>       Rate INT SPARSE NULL
>     )
> ```

```
namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Descript;
        public int? Rate;
    }
    class Program
    {
        public static DataTable ToDataTable(List<Test> items)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Descript", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Rate", typeof(int));

            foreach (Test item in items)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                row["ID"] = item.ID;
                row["Descript"] = item.Descript;
                if (item.Rate.HasValue) row["Rate"] = item.Rate;
                else row["Rate"] = DBNull.Value;

                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            return table;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<Test>();
            list.Add(new Test() { ID = 4, Descript = "1", Rate = 1 });
            list.Add(new Test() { ID = 5, Descript = "2", Rate = 2 });
            list.Add(new Test() { ID = 6, Descript = "3", Rate = 3 });
            list.Add(new Test() { ID = 7 });
            list.Add(new Test() { ID = 8, Descript = "3", Rate = 3 });
            list.Add(new Test() { ID = 9, Descript = "3", Rate = 3 });

            var Context = new Entities();

            SqlConnection ec = (SqlConnection)Context.Database.Connection;

            var copy = new SqlBulkCopy(ec, SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints, null);

            copy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.TestSparse";
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add("ID", "ID");
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add("Descript", "Descript");
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add("Rate", "Rate");

            ec.Open();
            var table = ToDataTable(list);
            copy.WriteToServer(table);
            copy.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, it is not because of the sparse columns. Do you have any column sets in your table?

> If a table has a **column_set**, sparse columns are not handled as distinct columns. The values of all sparse columns are included in the value of the **column_set**, which is exported in the same way as an XML column; that is, as **varbinary(max)** if bound as a binary type, or as **nvarchar(max)** if bound as a char or wchar type). On import, the **column_set** value must conform to the schema of the **column_set**.

You can find more details here
[Sparse Columns Support in SQL Server Native Client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280461(v=sql.110).aspx)